# Python Reportlab PDF - Centering Text on page

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am using [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) to generate a pdf dynamically with python.

I would like a line of text to be centered on a page.  Here is the specific code I currently have, but do not know how to center the text horizontally.

```
header = p.beginText(190, 740)
header.textOut("Title of Page Here")

# I know i can use TextLine etc in place of textOut

p.drawText(header)
```

The text displays and I can manually move the left position so the text looks centered, but I need this to be centered programmatically since the text will be dynamic and I don't know how much text there will be.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reportlab canvas has a [drawCentredString](http://www.reportlab.com/apis/reportlab/dev/pdfgen.html#reportlab.pdfgen.canvas.Canvas.drawCentredString) method. And yes, they spell it like that.

> We’re British, dammit, and proud of
>   our spelling!

**Edit**:
As for text objects, I'm afraid you don't. You can do something along those lines, though:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize

PAGE_WIDTH  = defaultPageSize[0]
PAGE_HEIGHT = defaultPageSize[1]

text = "foobar foobar foobar"
text_width = stringWidth(text)
y = 1050 # wherever you want your text to appear
pdf_text_object = canvas.beginText((PAGE_WIDTH - text_width) / 2.0, y)
pdf_text_object.textOut(text) # or: pdf_text_object.textLine(text) etc.
```

You can use other page sizes, obviously.

Comment: Thanks Jim,

I used 
p.drawCentredString(4.25*inch, 500, 'some text')

that works great, but how do I use drawCentredString with .textOut or .textLine?
 p.drawCentredString(center, 500, header);

Comment: defaultPageSize is not located in another place.

Import is `from reportlab.rl_settings import defaultPageSize`

Answer (score 7):

I just needed this too, and wrote this:

```
def createTextObject(canv, x, y, text, style, centered=False):
    font = (style.fontName, style.fontSize, style.leading)
    lines = text.split("\n")
    offsets = []
    if centered:
        maxwidth = 0
        for line in lines:
            offsets.append(canv.stringWidth(line, *font[:2]))
        maxwidth = max(*offsets)
        offsets = [(maxwidth - i)/2 for i in offsets]
    else:
        offsets = [0] * len(lines)
    tx = canv.beginText(x, y)
    tx.setFont(*font)
    for offset, line in zip(offsets, lines):
        tx.setXPos(offset)
        tx.textLine(line)
        tx.setXPos(-offset)
    return tx
```

Comment: +1 for using canvas.beginText :) Older answer but it works great! You do need to then draw `tx` that is returned to a canvas. Like `my_canvas.drawText(createTextObject(my_canvas, x, y, text, style, centered))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use Flowable object like `Paragraph` and assign `alignment` value to 1:

```
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
title_style = styles['Heading1']
title_style.alignment = 1
title = Paragraph("Hello Reportlab", title_style)
story.append(title)
```

This example will create a pdf document with centered text:

```
from flask import make_response
import io
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

story=[]
pdf_doc = io.BytesIO()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_doc)

styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
title_style = styles['Heading1']
title_style.alignment = 1
title = Paragraph("Hello Reportlab", title_style)
story.append(title)
doc.build(story)

content = pdf_doc.getvalue()

#output to browser
response = make_response(content)
response.mimetype = 'application/pdf'
return response
```

If you want the text to be floaten to the left, you need to change `alignment` to 0:

```
title_style.alignment = 0
```

If you want the text to be floaten to the right, you need to change `alignment` to 2:

```
title_style.alignment = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<para alignment="center">
```

As Per Reference : http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2006-June/005092.html

In your case:

```
header.textOut("<"para alignment='center'>"Title of Page Here")
```

Comment: Please copy a solution into your answer. External references are good just as an additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form_letter.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)
Story = []
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
title_style = styles['Heading1']
title_style.alignment = 1
title = Paragraph("Welcome to india", title_style)
Story.append(title)
doc.build(Story)
```